# Groupby certain number of rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with let's say 2 columns: dates and doubles

```
 2017-05-01   2.5
 2017-05-02   3.5
 ...          ...
 2017-05-17   0.2
 2017-05-18   2.5
```

Now I would like to do a groupby and sum with x rows. So i.e. with 6 rows it would return:

```
 2017-05-06  15.6
 2017-05-12  13.4
 2017-05-18  18.0
```

Is there a clean solution to do this without running it through a for-loop with something like this:

```
 temp = pd.DataFrame()
 j = 0
 for i in range(0,len(df.index),6):
      temp[df.ix[i]['date']] = df.ix[i:i+6]['value'].sum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for resample. consider this dataframe

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-05-01', periods=18, freq='D')
num = np.random.randint(5,size = 18)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'val': num})

df.resample('6D', on = 'date').sum().reset_index()
```

will return

```
    date        val
0   2017-05-01  14
1   2017-05-07  11
2   2017-05-13  16
```

Comment: I accepted before but when I tried your example I get the error: TypeError: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on' 
      args = ("resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'",) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of TypeError object>

Comment: I noticed I was using pandas 0.17, after upgrading it did work.

Comment: I am sorry I missed both the comments, glad that it worked out though

Answer (score 1):

This is alternative solution using `groupby` range of length of the dataframe.

**Two columns** using `agg`

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//6).agg(lambda x: {'date': x.date.iloc[0], 
                                                 'value': x.value.sum()})
```

**Multiple columns** you can use `first` (or `last`) for date and `sum` for other columns.

```
group = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//6)
pd.concat((group['date'].first(), 
           group[[c for c in df.columns if c != 'date']].sum()), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra, but how does that work when having more then 1 value columns, so a groupby would be better then x.value.sum()?

Comment: I'm not sure that I completely understand your question. This is basically group the Dataframe in chunk of 6 rows and aggregate those rows. I'm not sure if it's going to be better than plain summation.

Comment: Well now you have 'value' : x.value.sum() , but if there are 12 columns in the dataframe this means you have to write this for every column and with groupby this is for all at once.

Comment: Ah, I see! I will make my answer more general :)

Comment: @user3605780, I updated my solution. Hope it's more general now.