# How to groupby or resample by a specific number of rows -- using Dask (Python)

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, dask, pandas-resample

I'm trying to downsample Dask dataframes by any x number of rows.

For instance, if I was using datetimes as an index, I could just use:

```
df = df.resample('1h').ohlc()
```

But I don't want to resample by datetimes, I want to resample by a fixed number of rows...something like:

```
df = df.resample(rows=100).ohlc()
```

I did a bunch of searching and found these three old SO pages:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36810595/14179396) suggests:

  - `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//x)`, where x = the number of rows.
  - `pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]).mean(1))`, but I have trouble understanding this one.
  - `pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('ijk->ik',df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]))/2.0)`, but I also have trouble understanding this one.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44035640/14179396) suggests `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//x)` again.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44305794/14179396) suggests `df_sub = df.rolling(x).mean()[::x]`, but it says it's wasteful, and doesn't seem optimized for Dask.

The best, fastest option seems to be `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//x)`, and it works fine in Pandas. However, when I try it in Dask, I get: `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

How do I resample by # of rows using Dask?

I have dataframes with:

- A standard index (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5...,n)
- Datetime values I could potentially use as an index (although I don't necessarily want to)
- Non-standard lengths (i.e. Some of them have an even number of rows, and some have an odd number).