# Iterating over rows to find mean of a data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe of 100 random numbers and I would like to find the mean as follows:

mean0 should have mean of 0,5,10,... rows

mean1 should have mean of 1,6,11,16,.... rows

.

.

.
mean4 should have mean of 4,9,14,... rows.

So far, I am able to find the mean0 but I am not able to figure out a way to iterate the process in order to obtain the remaining means.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

df.to_csv('example.csv', index=False)

df1 = df[::5]
print("Every 12th row is:\n",df1)

df2 = df1.mean()
print(df2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Groupby certain number of rows pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035640/groupby-certain-number-of-rows-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the underlying numpy array:

```
df[0].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 5).mean(0)
```

output: `array([40.8 , 52.75, 43.2 , 55.05, 47.45])`

Comment: This gives me an error: 

raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 0

I don't understand why. Can you please help me?

Comment: Obviously, you should use the name of your column. In the provided example this was `0`. If the name is `'col'` -> `df['col']...`

Comment: When I tried to run the command with the code given above, it gives me the desired results but when I used the same command with df= pd.read_csv('example.csv'), it gives me the error. I haven't changed the name of the column in both the cases. Can you help me to understand what is wrong here?

Comment: Use `print(df.columns)` to see the column names. If you have `0` use `df[0]`, for `'0'` use `df['0']`. If you have a single column you can use positional indexing: `df.iloc[:,0]`. This is all basic pandas and had little to do with how my solution works. The pre-requisite is that you are able to select your column, and that the column contains a multiple of 5 elements.

Comment: Thanks! I renamed the column and it worked perfectly for me. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

Since `df[::5]` is equivalent to `df[0::5]`, you could use `df[1::5]`, `df[2::5]`, `df[3::5]`, and `df[4::5]` for the remaining dataframes with subsequent application of mean by `df[i::5].mean()`.

It is not explicitly showcased in the Pandas [documentation examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges) but identical list slicing with `[start:stop:step]`.